# nth word in a text

Tags: python, string

how can I find the nth word in a text.

example:

```
my_txt("hello to you all" , 3)

all
```

I don't wanna use any built in function ...and this is not a homework :D

Comment: If this isn't homework, then why don't you want to use built-in functions?

Comment: cause I want to learn to do it in the other possible ways

Comment: What level of built-in function are you willing to use?  `find`?  `split`?  The slice operator?

Comment: @user531225 in Python, there  should be only one good way to do anything. In this case, it's `str.split()`.

Comment: Not using builtins to solve problems is stupid. If this is not homework you don't even have someone else to blame. If you just want to reimplement builtins for practice you should first find out *which* function you want to do.

Comment: By the way, if you pass "3", this function should return "all", not "you".

Comment: lol .... stupid or not somehow/someday I want to understand how I can do this and learn it from root without built- in function...

Comment: In that case, I recommend assembly.

Comment: @user531225: That's like writing english without using the letter 'l' .. sure, you can just avoid words with it, or write 'i' instead and hope the people get it ... but in the end, all you learned is how to write *really badly*.

Comment: @Steve V: Or C. There you can avoid the whole stdlibrary, and just use pointers. :-)

Comment: You know, as much as we're harping on this guy for not wanting to use the built-in functions this is exactly the types of questions I've been asked at job interviews.

Comment: @wheaties They might stop you from using the built-in `min()` function when asking you to implement a minimum function of your own, but I'd be shocked if they put a blanket "no built-ins" at all. Built-ins exceed to all operators even in Python! So you have to define your limit.

Comment: Python is NOT the language to be trying to do stuff without builtins. If you really want to learn the deep down stuff, I suggest C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK you asked for this. You need a "split into words" function. Here it is. Assumes that "words" are delimited by whitespace.

No built-in functions, no imported anythings, no methods of built-in types, not even any panty-waist stuff like `+=`. And it's tested.

```
C:\junk>\python15\python
Python 1.5.2 (#0, Apr 13 1999, 10:51:12) [MSC 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Copyright 1991-1995 Stichting Mathematisch Centrum, Amsterdam
>>> def mysplit(s):
...     words = []
...     inword = 0
...     for c in s:
...         if c in " \r\n\t": # whitespace
...             inword = 0
...         elif not inword:
...             words = words + [c]
...             inword = 1
...         else:
...             words[-1] = words[-1] + c
...     return words
...
>>> mysplit('')
[]
>>> mysplit('x')
['x']
>>> mysplit('foo')
['foo']
>>> mysplit('  foo')
['foo']
>>> mysplit('  foo    ')
['foo']
>>> mysplit('\nfoo\tbar\rzot ugh\n\n   ')
['foo', 'bar', 'zot', 'ugh']
>>>
```

Answer (score 18):

The obvious way to do it is:

```
"hello to you all".split()[3]
```

The 80's way to do it is - that is, you have to walk the text, keeping note of the state of things you have found - it can become better than this, probably, but that is the idea. Perceive one has to use a lot o "built-in" functions either way. I just avoid the ones that make it straight like above.

```
def my_txt(text, target):
    count = 0
    last_was_space = False
    start = end = 0
    for index, letter in enumerate(text):
        if letter.isspace():
            if not last_was_space:
                 end = index
            last_was_space = True
        elif last_was_space:
            last_was_space = False
            count += 1
            if count > target:
                return text[start:end]
            elif count == target:
                start = index
    if count == target:
        return text[start:].strip()
    raise ValueError("Word not found")
```

Comment: enumerate, isspace, strip are all builtins. :) See how silly this gets?

Comment: See above. But +1 for making me go ... "oww! my head!" (on a related note, ever see how to extract a binary-string representation of a number in COBOL? :-)

Comment: Sorry, code review sez it's got a bug. `my_txt('   foo', 0)` produces a zero-length string. `my_text('    foo', 1)` produces `'foo'`. Looks like `last_was_space` should be initialised to `True`.

Comment: @pst: If that makes your head hurt, you'd better not read the real C implementation of `str.split` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since *everything* is a built in function in one way or another, I'm gonna ignore your claim to not want to use built in functions.

```
def my_txt(text, n):
    return text.split()[n]
```

Main drawback with this is that you'll get punctuation included. I leave it as exercise to figure out how to get rid of that. :)

Answer (score 1):

First let me say that I absolutely agree with the comments and the other answer, not using built in functions is stupid.  That being said, I found that attempting to write this code using as few built in *function calls* to be an interesting challenge, so I'll post what I came up with anyways.

```
def my_txt(txt, n, i=0):
    if n == 1:
        r = ""
        s = 0
        for c in txt:
            if s >= i:
                if c == " ":
                    return r
                r += c
            s += 1
    while txt[i] != " ":
        i += 1
    return my_txt(txt, n - 1, i + 1)

my_txt("hello to you all", 3) # returns 'you'
```

My self inflicted rules: no slices, comprehensions, generators, or built in function calls.

This code will horribly fail when attempting to get the last word (unless there is a trailing space) or for any `n` out of the range of words.

Comment: thx ... I can work with this and maybe after understanding the principle of it use range or len function

Comment: Clark: using a recursive function call is a bit of a cheat, isn't it?

Comment: He said no built in functions, I don't think recursion violates that.  Don't worry, your answer is still better :)

Answer (score 0):

obviously that's not without "built in functions" but it won't give error, no matter how hard u try :)

```
def my_text(string, integer=None):
  try:
    integer = int(integer)
  except ValueError:
    return 'enter a number'
  else:
    try:
      return string.split()[integer - 1]
    except IndexError:
      string = string.split()
      return f"text contains only {len(string)} word"

def inp():
  try:
    return int(input('Which word you need? ex: 1,2,3 etc.: '))
  except ValueError:
    return 'Enter number please'

print(my_text(input('Enter text here:  '), inp()))
```